# Dart read large file sync

Tags: dart, async-await

I need the ability to read a large tab delimited file a line at a time synchronously.  I found this async solution.  Can it be made sync using await?  Or is there a better sync method?

```
void readFileStream() {
  Stream<List<int>> stream = new File('./assets/user.json').openRead();
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  stream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .listen((data) {
      buffer.write(data);
    },
    onDone: () => print(buffer.toString()),
    onError: (e) => print(e));
}
```

Comment: You can't make asynchronous functions synchronous.  However, `File` already provides both asynchronous and synchronous interfaces.  For example, [`File.readAsStringSync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/readAsStringSync.html).

Comment: @jamesdlin I think the question is saying OP wants to be able to iterate through each individual line in a file that is too big to open all at once in memory, but do it in a synchronous way. In theory this is possible using `File.openSync` and subsequent uses of `RandomAccessFile.readByteSync` to decode characters one at a time until a newline is detected, but at that point I have to question if it's even worth it to not just do the whole thing asynchronously. (I don't know of a built-in method that does this for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make an async operation synchronous using `await`, or in any other way. Being synchronous means returning a result immediately, being asynchronous means the result isn't available immediately.

For reading synchronously, you can read a byte at a time until you reach a newline, but that's likely going to be very slow.
A more reasonable approach is to read chunks and split them into lines.

Maybe something like:

```dart
import "dart:io";
import "dart:convert";
import "dart:collection";

Iterable<String> readLinesSync(File file) sync* {
  var f = file.openSync(); // creates a RandomAccessFile
  var lineBuffer = Queue<String>();
  var sink = utf8.decoder.startChunkedConversion(
    LineSplitter().startChunkedConversion(_Sink(lineBuffer.add)));

  bool done = false;
  do {
    do {
      var chunk = f.readSync(256);
      sink.add(chunk);
      if (chunk.length < 256) {
        done = true;
        sink.close(); 
        break; 
      }
    } while (lineBuffer.isEmpty)
    while (lineBuffer.isNotEmpty) {
      yield lineBuffer.removeFirst(); 
    }
  } while (!done);
}

class _Sink<T> implements Sink<T> {
  void Function(T) _add;
  _Sink(this._add);
  void add(T value) {
    _add(value);
  }
  void close() {}
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I do realize that async and sync are not the same but I was hoping to push the required async functions into a single async function and then force a bit of synchrony by calling them in order and use await on each one.  So I was hoping that the method I listed could be broken down into multiple calls that could be prefaced by "await"

Comment: Maybe you can use [`SteamIterator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamIterator-class.html) from the platform libraries or [`StreamQueue`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue-class.html) from `package:async` to read the stream you created incrementally. Would that be something like what you are looking for?